# merge outputs of two sql queries

Tags: sql, join, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to merge (left inner join) the outputs of these two sql queries based on the "date" column. However, I am unable to figure out an appropriate syntax since one of these is a cte and there are already many joins here.

Query1:

```
(SELECT
    (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS "d_dates.date_date",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (( (f_traffic."D_TIMES_ID") = -1  )) AND (( d_platforms."PLATFORM"  ) = 'App') THEN ( f_traffic."VISITS" ) ELSE NULL END), 0) AS app_adobe
FROM DATA_MART.F_TRAFFIC  AS f_traffic
INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_DATES  AS d_dates ON (f_traffic."WH_DATE_ID") = (d_dates."ID")
INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_OBJECTS  AS d_objects ON
             (f_traffic."D_OBJECTS_ID") = (d_objects."ID")
INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_PLATFORMS  AS d_platforms ON (f_traffic."D_PLATFORMS_ID") = (d_platforms."ID")
WHERE ((( d_dates."DAY"  ) >= ((TO_DATE(DATEADD('day', -2, CURRENT_DATE())))) AND ( d_dates."DAY"  ) < ((TO_DATE(DATEADD('day', 2, DATEADD('day', -2, CURRENT_DATE()))))))) AND (d_objects."OBJECT_GROUP" ) = 'WELT' AND (d_objects."OBJECT_NAME" ) = 'WELT'
GROUP BY
    (TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" ))
ORDER BY
    1)
```

Query2:

```
(WITH f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data AS (SELECT
      coalesce (f_ivw_measures.WH_DATE_ID, f_ivw_forecasts.WH_DATE_ID, f_ivw_plan_data.WH_DATE_ID)  AS WH_DATE_ID..,,,
      f_ivw_plan_data.PLANNED_PAGE_IMPRESSIONS,
      case when to_date(concat(left(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,4),'-' ,substr(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,5,2),'-',right(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,2)
      ))  >= current_date then  f_ivw_forecasts.VISITS else f_ivw_measures.VISITS end  AS VISITS_FORECAST,
      case when to_date(concat(left(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,4),'-' ,substr(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,5,2),'-',right(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,2)
      ))  >= current_date then  f_ivw_forecasts.PAGE_IMPRESSIONS else f_ivw_measures.PAGE_IMPRESSIONS end AS PAGE_IMPRESSIONS_FORECAST
 FROM DATA_MART.F_IVW_MEASURES AS f_ivw_measures
      FULL OUTER JOIN DATA_MART.F_IVW_FORECASTS AS f_ivw_forecasts
        ON f_ivw_measures.WH_DATE_ID = f_ivw_forecasts.WH_DATE_ID
      AND f_ivw_measures.D_IVW_OFFERS_ID = f_ivw_forecasts.D_IVW_OFFERS_ID
      AND f_ivw_measures.D_IVW_CODES_ID = f_ivw_forecasts.D_IVW_CODES_ID
      FULL OUTER JOIN DATA_MART.F_IVW_PLANNING_DATA AS f_ivw_plan_data
        ON f_ivw_measures.WH_DATE_ID = f_ivw_plan_data.WH_DATE_ID
      AND f_ivw_measures.D_IVW_OFFERS_ID = f_ivw_plan_data.D_IVW_OFFERS_ID
       )
SELECT
    (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS "d_dates.date_date",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ((( d_ivw_offers."OFFER"  ) NOT IN ('AWPBILD', 'CTVBILD') OR (( d_ivw_offers."OFFER"  )) IS NULL)) AND (( d_platforms."PLATFORM"  ) = 'Desktop') THEN ( f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data."VISITS"  )  ELSE NULL END), 0) AS web,
FROM f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data
INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_DATES  AS d_dates ON (f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data."WH_DATE_ID") = (d_dates."ID")
INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_OBJECTS  AS d_objects ON (f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data."D_OBJECTS_ID") = (d_objects."ID")
WHERE (((( d_dates."DAY"  )) < (TO_DATE(DATEADD('minute', 0, DATE_TRUNC('minute', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())))))) AND (d_objects."OBJECT_GROUP" ) = 'WELT' AND (d_objects."OBJECT_NAME" ) = 'WELT'
GROUP BY
    (TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" ))
ORDER BY
    5 DESC)
```

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Does `UNION`  or `UNION ALL` work for you, or rather, are you looking to join the outputs to have unique columns? Please provide sample expected output.

Comment: left inner join @Isolated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using one in a CTE - why not build upon that example?

```
(WITH f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data AS (SELECT
              coalesce (f_ivw_measures.WH_DATE_ID, f_ivw_forecasts.WH_DATE_ID, f_ivw_plan_data.WH_DATE_ID)  AS WH_DATE_ID..,,,
              f_ivw_plan_data.PLANNED_PAGE_IMPRESSIONS,
              case when to_date(concat(left(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,4),'-' ,substr(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,5,2),'-',right(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,2)
              ))  >= current_date then  f_ivw_forecasts.VISITS else f_ivw_measures.VISITS end  AS VISITS_FORECAST,
              case when to_date(concat(left(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,4),'-' ,substr(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,5,2),'-',right(f_ivw_forecasts."WH_DATE_ID" ,2)
              ))  >= current_date then  f_ivw_forecasts.PAGE_IMPRESSIONS else f_ivw_measures.PAGE_IMPRESSIONS end AS PAGE_IMPRESSIONS_FORECAST
         FROM DATA_MART.F_IVW_MEASURES AS f_ivw_measures
              FULL OUTER JOIN DATA_MART.F_IVW_FORECASTS AS f_ivw_forecasts
                ON f_ivw_measures.WH_DATE_ID = f_ivw_forecasts.WH_DATE_ID
              AND f_ivw_measures.D_IVW_OFFERS_ID = f_ivw_forecasts.D_IVW_OFFERS_ID
              AND f_ivw_measures.D_IVW_CODES_ID = f_ivw_forecasts.D_IVW_CODES_ID
              FULL OUTER JOIN DATA_MART.F_IVW_PLANNING_DATA AS f_ivw_plan_data
                ON f_ivw_measures.WH_DATE_ID = f_ivw_plan_data.WH_DATE_ID
              AND f_ivw_measures.D_IVW_OFFERS_ID = f_ivw_plan_data.D_IVW_OFFERS_ID
               )
,    
web_traffic AS (
        SELECT
            (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS "d_dates.date_date",
            COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ((( d_ivw_offers."OFFER"  ) NOT IN ('AWPBILD', 'CTVBILD') OR (( d_ivw_offers."OFFER"  )) IS NULL)) AND (( d_platforms."PLATFORM"  ) = 'Desktop') THEN ( f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data."VISITS"  )  ELSE NULL END), 0) AS web,
        FROM f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data
        INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_DATES  AS d_dates ON (f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data."WH_DATE_ID") = (d_dates."ID")
        INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_OBJECTS  AS d_objects ON (f_ivw_measures_with_plan_data."D_OBJECTS_ID") = (d_objects."ID")
        WHERE (((( d_dates."DAY"  )) < (TO_DATE(DATEADD('minute', 0, DATE_TRUNC('minute', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())))))) AND (d_objects."OBJECT_GROUP" ) = 'WELT' AND (d_objects."OBJECT_NAME" ) = 'WELT'
        GROUP BY
            (TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" ))
        ORDER BY
            5 DESC)
,    
app_adobe_traffic AS (
    SELECT
        (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS "d_dates.date_date",
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (( (f_traffic."D_TIMES_ID") = -1  )) AND (( d_platforms."PLATFORM"  ) = 'App') THEN ( f_traffic."VISITS" ) ELSE NULL END), 0) AS app_adobe
    FROM DATA_MART.F_TRAFFIC  AS f_traffic
    INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_DATES  AS d_dates ON (f_traffic."WH_DATE_ID") = (d_dates."ID")
    INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_OBJECTS  AS d_objects ON
                 (f_traffic."D_OBJECTS_ID") = (d_objects."ID")
    INNER JOIN DATA_MART.D_PLATFORMS  AS d_platforms ON (f_traffic."D_PLATFORMS_ID") = (d_platforms."ID")
    WHERE ((( d_dates."DAY"  ) >= ((TO_DATE(DATEADD('day', -2, CURRENT_DATE())))) AND ( d_dates."DAY"  ) < ((TO_DATE(DATEADD('day', 2, DATEADD('day', -2, CURRENT_DATE()))))))) AND (d_objects."OBJECT_GROUP" ) = 'WELT' AND (d_objects."OBJECT_NAME" ) = 'WELT'
    GROUP BY
        (TO_DATE(d_dates."DAY" ))
    ORDER BY
        1)
    
SELECT COALESCE(web."d_dates.date_date", adb."d_dates.date_date") as date_date,
COALESCE(web.web, 0) AS web_traffic,
COALESCE(adb.app_adobe, 0) AS app_adobe_traffic
    FROM web_traffic web
    FULL OUTER JOIN app_adobe_traffic adb
    ON web."d_dates.date_date" = adb."d_dates.date_date"
    
    )
```

In this instance, I'm taking the naive approach that there is the potential that traffic could exist in either system and not necessarily always in both, which is why I used the full outer join in the final select. This could be swapped out for a left join if desired.